# Printing out specific row in ArrayList without using index

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I want to be able print out a specific row/line in an ArrayList but right now I can only print out all rows in the ArrayList.

I have a class called "TestarIgen" where I have the variables: Kontonummer, Saldo and Kredit along with their get & set methods.

In the Main class I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<TestarIgen> testList = new ArrayList<>();

    testList.add(new TestarIgen(1, 1, 1));
    testList.add(new TestarIgen(2, 2, 2));

    String titelRad = "%-10s %6s %6s\n";
    String template = "%-10s %6d %6s\n";

    System.out.printf(titelRad, "Kontonummer ", "Saldo ", "Kredit");
    for (TestarIgen testarigen : testList) {
        System.out.printf(template, testarigen.getKontoNr(), testarigen.getSaldo(), testarigen.getKredit());
    }
}
```

I want to be able to select which row to print out, based on which row that contains a specific "Kontonummer". How is this possible?

Comment: Well, you iterate through the elements, you test if the element contains the specific "Kontonummer", and if it does, you print the element, and you break out of the loop.

Comment: @JBNizet ...or better yet build a map to be able to answer multiple queries of the same type.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but complexity is a word you cannot leave out of here.

The first and maybe naive solution would be to simply search for the correct *Kontonummer* like this:

```
List <TestarIgen> testList = new ArrayList <>();

int kontonummer = 1;
for (TestarIgen testarigen : testList) {
    if(testarigen.getKontoNr() == kontonummer) {
         // match found
         break; // stop the loop if we found a match, saves some time
    }
}
```

This solution has a complexity of `O(n)`, which means that in the worst case, you have to iterate through all elements in the list. Luckily, Java has other data structures that have a better complexity - `Map` for example. If you have ever seen the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of an Object, they come into play here again and *usually* reduce the complexity to `O(1)`. On average, Java takes only one operation to find the key you are looking for. So, a better solution would be the following:

```
Map<Integer, TestarIgen> map = new HashMap<>();

for (TestarIgen testarigen : testList) {
    map.put(testarigen.getKontoNr(), testarigen);
}

int kontonummer = 1;
TestarIgen value = map.get(kontonummer);
if(value != null) {
    // the map contains your value
} else {
    // the map does not contain your value
}
```

While it might not be relevant in your example, it is best practise and matters when data sets are getting bigger.

**Other improvements:**

What about adding a `toString` method to your `TestarIgen` class? Then your printing can be reduced to the following:

```
System.out.printf(testarigen);
```

**Java 8:**

If you like to use Java 8, the loop statement can be simplified to:

```
testarigen.stream().filter(t -> t.getKontoNr() == kontonummer).findFirst()
        .ifPresent(System.out::print);
```

This stream has a complexity of `O(n)`. Also note that i did make use of the previously recommended `toString` method here.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the need of a`Map` collection . You can construct it in one pass through the list and build it as:

```
Map <Integer, TestarIgen> map = new HashMap<>();
for(TestarIgen ti : testList){
   map.put(ti.getKontoNr(), ti);
}
```

once you have it you can get the corresponding the object with `Kontonummer = x` in the following way:

```
TestarIgen obj = map.get(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest using `java-8`.  With your `List` you can `filter` the `stream` in order to grab what element you want by condition without having to use an index.

### TestarIgen

```
public class TestarIgen {
    private int kontonummer;
    private int saldo;
    private int kredit;

    public TestarIgen(int kontunummer, int saldo, int kredit) {
        this.kontonummer = kontunummer;
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.kredit = kredit;
    }

    public int getKontoNr() {
        return this.kontonummer;
    }

    public int getSaldo() {
        return this.saldo;
    }

    public int getKredit() {
        return this.kredit;
    }
}
```

### Usage

What is demonstrated will grab the `first` matching element.  If you want something other than the first result, you'll have to add more logic to the code, but this should get you going.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestarIgen> testList = new ArrayList<TestarIgen>();

        testList.add(new TestarIgen(1, 1, 1));
        testList.add(new TestarIgen(2, 2, 2));

        String titelRad = "%-10s %6s %6s\n";
        String template = "%-10s %6d %6s\n";

        System.out.printf(titelRad, "Kontonummer ", "Saldo ", "Kredit");
        TestarIgen test = testList.stream().filter(t -> t.getKontoNr() == 1).findFirst().get();
        System.out.printf(template, test.getKontoNr(), test.getSaldo(), test.getKredit());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Kontonummer  Saldo  Kredit
1               1      1
```

Comment: Altough irrelavant in this example, calling `Optional.get` without `Optional.isPresent` first is an antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

Using java 8 and streams

```
 static void printRow(int kontoNummer, List<TestarIgen> list) {
    String template = "%-10s %6d %6s\n";
    list.stream()
        .filter(t -> t.getKontoNr() == kontoNummer)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(t -> System.out.printf(template, t.getKontoNr(), t.getSaldo(), t.getKredit()));
}

...

printRow(2, testList);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution which uses an index - note that this is a way to search efficiently - though the requirement says (in the post title) that 'without using index'.

This uses [Collections.binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)). Note that the `List` needs to be sorted on the attribute on which the search is conducted. The result is got by random access (not a sequential search). This may be useful for searching a `List` collection for a faster search.

```
   import java.util.*;
    public class ListSearch {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<TestarIgen> testList = new ArrayList<>();
            testList.add(new TestarIgen(1, 1, 1));
            testList.add(new TestarIgen(2, 2, 2));
            testList.add(new TestarIgen(12, 2, 2));
            testList.add(new TestarIgen(4, 2, 2));
            System.out.println(testList); // unsorted list: [1-1-1, 2-2-2, 12-2-2, 4-2-2]
            // Sort by Kontonummer using a Comparator
            Comparator<TestarIgen> kontonummerComparator = new Comparator<TestarIgen>() {
                public int compare(TestarIgen one, TestarIgen two) {
                    return Integer.compare(one.getKontoNr(), two.getKontoNr());
                }
            };
            Collections.sort(testList, kontonummerComparator);
            System.out.println(testList); // sorted list by Kontonummer: [1-1-1, 2-2-2, 4-2-2, 12-2-2]
            // Search the list with Kontonummer using binary search
            TestarIgen searchKey = new TestarIgen(4, 2, 2);
            int index = Collections.binarySearch(testList, searchKey, kontonummerComparator);
            System.out.println(index); // prints row index 2
            System.out.println(testList.get(index)); // 4-2-2 where Kontonummer is 4!
        }
    }
    class TestarIgen {
        private int kontonummer;
        private int saldo;
        private int kredit;
        public TestarIgen(int kontunummer, int saldo, int kredit) {
            this.kontonummer = kontunummer;
            this.saldo = saldo;
            this.kredit = kredit;
        }
        public int getKontoNr() {
            return kontonummer;
        }
        public int getSaldo() {
            return saldo;
        }
        public int getKredit() {
            return kredit;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return kontonummer + "-" + saldo + "-" + kredit;
        }
    }
```